# Android Twilio IP messaging issue

Tags: android, twilio, message

When I configuring Twilio Android sample application from https://github.com/llSourcell/IPMQuickstart-Android and I got this error:

```
05-30 18:05:19.949: I/IPMessagingClient(native)(2780):    1431675320 | 05/30/18:05:19.961 | WARNING  | 3   | TNNotificationClient | onTwilsockError: 0 - Poco ws exception while connecting: WebSocket Exception: Cannot upgrade to WebSocket connection: Capability tokens are not supported, TNNotificationClient
```

I am sure capability token generating very well.

How I can set **IP Messaging Service SID**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Downloaded and installed server app from https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/ip-messaging/guides/quickstart-js

Now application get access token very well.